# Где на сервере найти файл .sql?

Tags: sql, сервер

дали доступ по SFTP на сервер. Там есть папка с сайтом + папка phpmyadmin. В какой папке можно найти файл .sql для импорта в базу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кратко отвечу, что наличие файла .sql на сервере не очевидно. Его создают либо вручную, либо бекапом. Просто так он сам не генерируется.

**Можно найти все файлы с расширением .sql:**

Попробуйте подключиться через командную строку в терминале.

1. На windows нажмите клавиши Win+R -> введите cmd и нажмите enter
2. На mac os x -> в поиске введите terminal (терминал)

введите ssh НАЗВАНИЕ_ВАШЕГО_ЮЗЕРА@IP_ИЛИ_NAME_СЕРВЕРА -p ПОРТ(если он не 22)
например: ssh webuser@173.23.44.10 -p 60222 (это как пример) и нажмите enter
введите пароль

Если смогли войти на сервер, то введите команду и нажмите enter:

`find / |grep -e "\.sql$"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в ssh доступа нет, то сложно понять, а есть ли он на сервере и куда его положили, этот sql.

**Дополнение:**

Если есть доступ в ssh-терминал, то можно выгрузить sql из базы данных:

вводите команду

```
mysqldump -uПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ_БАЗЫ -p НАЗВАНИЕ_ТАБЛИЦЫ > database.sql
```

например `mysqldump -umy_user -p autoparts > autoparts.sql`

Файлик sql окажется в том же каталоге, откуда вызвали команду

команда `pwd` покажет где вы находитесь

Заливаем бекап в базу данных `mysql -umy_user -pPASSWORD autoparts < autoparts.sql`